# Makefile 自体を exec することはできる？

Tags: linux, makefile

タスクランナーとして、しばしば Makefile を利用します。

長い時間、インタラクティブに利用するようなプロセスを実行する場合、だったら exec を実行したいなと思う場合があります。具体的には、 docker run に諸々のオプションをつけて、 `-it` で bash するような場合です。

#### 質問

- Makefile において、その Make プロセス自体を exec させることは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

できないと思います。インタラクティブなプロセスなら `tmux`(1) や `screen`(1) でバックグラウンドに起動するといいんじゃないでしょうかね。

`Makefile` での例ではないけど、こんな↓感じ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426159/starting-a-new-tmux-session-and-detaching-it-all-inside-a-shell-script

…

余談。最初についた回答に `make`(1posix) の例が載っていますが、この例はよくないですね。こう↓しないとタスク走らないし危険だと思います。

```
.PHONY: subdir
subdir:
    cd subdir && rm all_the_files && $(MAKE)
```

Answer (score 0):

[POSIX Programmer's Manual の make の記載](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/make.1posix.html)にお探しの部分に近い Makefile の記載があります。

```
subdir:
   cd subdir; rm all_the_files; $(MAKE)
```

上記エントリでは、`subdir` ターゲットが呼び出されると、`subdir` ディレクトリに移動し、ファイルを削除してから $(MAKE) マクロ(`make`) コマンドを実行しています。